# How to convert microseconds to hh:mm:ss to navigate to a particular time in youtube video?

Tags: python, datetime, youtube

I have a timestep (e.g. `2717715` `microseconds`) which I want to convert to hh:mm:ss format to extract a frame from a youtube video. I have used the following code to do so:

```
def convert(timestamp):
    # pdb.set_trace()
    timestamp = float(timestamp)
    # seconds = (micros/1000)%60
    # minutes = (micros/(1000*60))%60
    # hours = (micros/(1000*60*60))%24
    # pdb.set_trace
    milliseconds   = (timestamp / 1000) % 1000
    seconds    = (( (timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000)%60 
    minutes    = (((( (timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000) - seconds)/60) %60 
    hours      = ((((((timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000) - seconds)/60) - minutes)/60

    return  hours, minutes, seconds
```

But it is not working. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your timestamp is of type float you can use the built in [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#divmod) function as follows:

```
timestamp = 3 * 3600 + 7 * 60 + 20 # just creating (3h 7m 20s) float format timestamp
print(timestamp)  # gives 11240
```

suppose you have that timestamp, you can extract your hours, minutes and seconds from it as follows:

```
timestamp = float(timestamp)/1000000 # The timestamp is in microseconds
hours,remainder = divmod(timestamp, 3600)
minutes,seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
print(hours)  # gives 3
print(minutes) # gives 7
print(seconds) # gives 20
```

Hope that helped. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module.

You can get a human-readable time from a timestamp in the following manner:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).time()
```

Comment: what if the timestamp is in microseconds?